# Recursively replace characters in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, recursion

How do I change all dots `.` to underscores (in the dict's keys), **given an arbitrarily nested dictionary**?

What I tried is write two loops, but then I would be limited to 2-level-nested dictionaries.

This ...

```
{
    "brown.muffins": 5,
    "green.pear": 4,
    "delicious.apples": {
        "green.apples": 2
    {
}
```

... should become:

```
{
    "brown_muffins": 5,
    "green_pear": 4,
    "delicious_apples": {
        "green_apples": 2
    {
}
```

Is there an elegant way?

Comment: Define method to loop over dictionary keys/values, if key has dot, replace, if value is another dict, enter recursion (call the same method but now with this dict)

Comment: What have you tried? Don't get that 'arbitrarely nested' with 'got two loops'.

Comment: The beauty of recursion, baby

Comment: @BobDylan What if it recurses past the stack limit?

Comment: @PeterWood - That's a possibility with any recursion. If the structure isn't nested very deeply, it'll probably be fine.

Comment: @PeterWood stack overflow, baby :P

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The question says *given an arbitrarily nested dictionary*, so that rules out recursion in my mind.

Comment: @PeterWood - Well, it seems to be the popular answer (but `ast.literal_eval()` itself is probably recursive, too). A 1000-level dictionary is probably a bit of an edge case, anyway, and that value can be increased if desired.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can write a recursive function, like this

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
def rec_key_replace(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Mapping):
        return {key.replace('.', '_'): rec_key_replace(val) for key, val in obj.items()}
    return obj
```

and when you invoke this with the dictionary you have shown in the question, you will get a new dictionary, with the dots in keys replaced with `_`s

```
{'delicious_apples': {'green_apples': 2}, 'green_pear': 4, 'brown_muffins': 5}
```

**Explanation**

Here, we just check if the current object is an instance of `dict` and if it is, then we iterate the dictionary, replace the key and call the function recursively. If it is actually not a dictionary, then return it as it is.

Comment: why not `dict` instead of `Mapping` ?

Comment: @IronFist When you check if it is an instance of `dict`, you are restricting it to just `dict` and its subclasses. Instead, you relax the condition a little and allow any class which has few methods which would make it look like a dictionary. You might want to look at [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping) definition.

Comment: forgive lack of knowledge here..:P .. One more thing, it's just as suggestion, don't you think it's safe to wrap it with `tr-except` block to be safe from reaching maximum iteration if that matters, and raise an exception when so or any control measure against it...?

Comment: @IronFist This is not production ready code :D I don't expect anyone to use it as it is. They can increase the recursion limit if they like :-)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `.` is only present in keys and all the dictionary's contents are primitive literals, the really cheap way would be to use `str()` or `repr()`, do the replacement, then `ast.literal_eval()` to get it back:

```
d ={
    "brown.muffins": 5,
    "green.pear": 4,
    "delicious_apples": {
        "green.apples": 2
    } # correct brace
}
```

Result:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(repr(d).replace('.','_'))
{'delicious_apples': {'green_apples': 2}, 'green_pear': 4, 'brown_muffins': 5}
```

If the dictionary has `.` outside of keys, we can replace more carefully by using a regular expression to look for strings like `'ke.y':` and replace only those bits:

```
>>> import re
>>> ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r"'(.*?)':", lambda x: x.group(0).replace('.','_'), repr(d)))
{'delicious_apples': {'green_apples': 2}, 'green_pear': 4, 'brown_muffins': 5}
```

If your dictionary is very complex, with `'.'` in values and dictionary-like strings and so on, use a real recursive approach. Like I said at the start, though, this is the cheap way.

Comment: That would also replace in the values, though

Comment: @cricket_007 I think he's talking about integral amounts of fruits and confections.

Comment: @erip - still not what OP asked

Comment: Assuming you don't have `{'my.key': __my_method}` :P

Comment: @erip ideally, it should also be useful for future visitors, not just OPs specific case. Very creative nonetheless

Comment: As I say in my profile: "If I have to choose between answering a question and solving a problem, I'll pick the latter every time."

Comment: I love the idea of *literally* editing the dict. Seems a bit unsafe, but thanks for broadening my horizon!

Comment: @Xiphias *Seems a bit unsafe* - it's perfectly safe

Comment: @Tim Castelijns: Ah, now it's only about the keys. Wonderful!

Comment: 1) This solution works only for data structures containing built-in types. 2) Even if you replace `ast.literal_eval` with `eval` it still won't work for types not conforming `eval(repr(x)) == x`.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский - 1) The question didn't mention the use of non-primitives. Since primitives are very common, it would be reasonable for this data structure to only contain such. If it doesn't, that can be clarified in an edit. 2) `eval(repr(x)) == x` is the correct behavior of those functions. Since (as seen in 1) this answer assumes primitive types, which satisfy this condition, it would be pretty difficult to mess with that anyway. I find this to be a perfectly reasonable, straightforward solution.

Comment: This is the most literal interpretation of the question -- not at all a bad thing, and *I* certainly learned something useful about Python. There's already, as @TigerhawkT3 stated, a proper recursive function answer that's for *"production level"* implementations, but this is cool for the lazy programmer.