# Replace None in a python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nonetype

I happen to have a complex dictionary (having lists, dicts within lists etc). The values for some of the keys are set as **None**

Is there a way I can replace this **None** with some default value of my own irrespective of the complex structure of the dictionary?

Comment: Do you want to replace the `None` in nested dictionaries also?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know there's no shortcut approach, you have to traverse the `dict` and any values in it which are containers, replacing `None`s as you go. This sounds like a good job for recursion.

Comment: @MariusSiuram: The OP wants to replace _values_ which are `None`, not keys.

Comment: @Marius: no, he means, 'some values' by 'the values for some of the keys' :)

Comment: Or, alternatively, what do you expect for the following data structure: `{1: 'one', 2: [1, 2, None], '3': None, None: {None: None, 2: [1,2, None, {None: None, 2: None}]}}`

Comment: @MariusSiuram, Yes, my dict is similar to the one you posted. The difference being I wont have a None inside a list. None will be a value inside a nested dict and I intend to replace all of them

Comment: Related: [Recursively replace characters in a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615164/recursively-replace-characters-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: Related: [Convert python decimal to string in deeply nested and unpredictable list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22080079/4279)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it using `object_pairs_hook` from `json` module:

```
def dict_clean(items):
    result = {}
    for key, value in items:
        if value is None:
            value = 'default'
        result[key] = value
    return result

dict_str = json.dumps(my_dict)
my_dict = json.loads(dict_str, object_pairs_hook=dict_clean)
```

Comment: Alternative implementation for the function: `return {k: v if v is not None else 'default' for k, v in items}`.

Comment: I would also have a `default` parameter for the `dict_clean` function.

Comment: Not sure if optimal, but definitely quite elegant. Though, this may fail if the dict contains any unserializable object.

Answer (score 17):

```
# replace_none_with_empty_str_in_dict.py

raw = {'place': 'coffee shop', 'time': 'noon', 'day': None}

def replace_none_with_empty_str(some_dict):
    return { k: ('' if v is None else v) for k, v in some_dict.items() }

print(replace_none_with_empty_str(raw))
```

Comment: tested with Python 3.5.3

Comment: awesome 1 liner

Answer (score 4):

Here's a recursive solution that also replaces `None`s inside lists.

First we define a simple class, `Null`, to act as the replacement for `None`.

```
class Null(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Null'

NULL = Null()

def replace_none(data):
    for k, v in data.items() if isinstance(data, dict) else enumerate(data):
        if v is None:
            data[k] = NULL
        elif isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
            replace_none(v)

# Test
data = {
    1: 'one', 
    2: ['two', 2, None], 
    3: None, 
    4: {4: None, 44: 'four'},
    5:  {
            5: [55, 56, None], 
            6: {66: None, 67: None},
            8: [88, {9:'nine', 99:None}, 100]
        }
}

print(data)
replace_none(data)
print(data)
```

**output**

```
{1: 'one', 2: ['two', 2, None], 3: None, 4: {44: 'four', 4: None}, 5: {8: [88, {9: 'nine', 99: None}, 100], 5: [55, 56, None], 6: {66: None, 67: None}}}
{1: 'one', 2: ['two', 2, Null], 3: Null, 4: {44: 'four', 4: Null}, 5: {8: [88, {9: 'nine', 99: Null}, 100], 5: [55, 56, Null], 6: {66: Null, 67: Null}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if v is None:
        my_dict[k] = "my default value"
```

Comment: The question seems quite explicit about `None`, so I should advise `v is None` instead of `not v`, as this last option would change empty strings, false values, number 0...

Comment: Agreed, `None` is less that `not v`.

Comment: @LutzHorn That solution will work if the value is at the first level. In my case, the value is deep within the dict (inside a dict within a list within a dict) and the solution fails

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a sample of your *real* input.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive solution from Lutz:

```
def replace(any_dict):
    for k, v in any_dict.items():
        if v is None:
            any_dict[k] = "my default value"
        elif type(v) == type(any_dict):
            replace(v)

replace(my_dict)
```

Comment: what is the "elif type(v) == type(any_dict): replace(v)" part? Sounds pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with recursive function that iterates over all dicts and lists:

```
def convert(obj):
    if type(obj) == list:
        for x in obj:
            convert(x)
    elif type(obj) == dict:
        for k, v in obj.iteritems():
            if v is None:
                obj[k] = 'DEFAULT'
            else:
                convert(v)

data = {1: 'foo', 2: None, 3: [{1: 'foo', 2: None}]}
convert(data)
print data # -> {1: 'foo', 2: 'DEFAULT', 3: [{1: 'foo', 2: 'DEFAULT'}]}
```